# mean angular 2 express: get route() only returns "/" route

Tags: angular, express, mean-stack

Hello I'm creating an Angular2 mean stack app. I believe the call for the second route is not called correctly.The network response is html and not JSON

```
import express = require('express');
import path = require('path');

import ContactRoutes = require('../routes/ContactRoutes');
import EstimateRoutes = require('../routes/EstimateRoutes');
var app = express();

class Routes {
    get routes() {
        app.use("/", new ContactRoutes().routes);
        app.use("/estimates", new EstimateRoutes().routes);
        return app;
    }
}
export = Routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The solution I found was to add the root "/" to both uses.

> ```
> app.use("/", new ContactRoutes().routes);
> app.use("/", new EstimateRoutes().routes);
> ```

not sure how the route is determined but it works.

Comment: The routes within `EstimateRoutes` probably already include the prefix.